# Get access to the live preview logs of wordpress theme deployed by bitnami on a GCP VM

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, ram, bitnami

I wanted to deploy [this wordpress theme](https://themeforest.net/item/luwix-data-science-analytics-wordpress-theme/37568282) to a GCP VM, using bitnami and the free tier, following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Xq2tBCvhiU). I am able to deploy a the default themes but, unfortunately, when I upload my own and click *Live preview* I get the following message:

> There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your
> site admin email inbox for instructions.
>
> Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress.

The first thing I thought when I searched the Internet was that my machine did not have enough RAM memory as explained in [this forum post](https://community.bitnami.com/t/there-has-been-a-critical-error-on-this-website-error-message-appears-when-trying-to-log-in/92687/4):

So I tried to open the logs with SSH on the GCP virtual machine but the VM seems to be empty.

```
officialdataguild@cloudshell:~ (the-data-guild-website)$ gcloud compute ssh wordpress-website-vm --project=the-data-guild-website
Did you mean zone [europe-west1-c] for instance: [wordpress-website-vm] (Y/n)?  n

No zone specified. Using zone [us-east1-b] for instance: [wordpress-website-vm].
Updating project ssh metadata...working.Updated [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/the-data-guild-website].
Updating project ssh metadata...done.
Waiting for SSH key to propagate.
Warning: Permanently added 'compute.2745993064748503787' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Linux wordpress-website-vm 4.19.0-20-cloud-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.235-1 (2022-03-17) x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
officialdataguild@wordpress-website-vm:~$ ls
officialdataguild@wordpress-website-vm:~$
```

Following [this tutorial on viewing and examining logs](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/216512217-Viewing-and-examining-your-error-log-via-SSH) I looked for the right folder but wasn't able to find it:

```
officialdataguild@wordpress-website-vm:~$ cd ~/logs
-bash: cd: /home/officialdataguild/logs: No such file or directory
```

So, following this [guide to troubleshoot preblems with wordpress deployed with bitnami](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/troubleshoot-wordpress-issues/) I went a folder down and did:

```
officialdataguild@wordpress-website-vm:~$ cd ..
officialdataguild@wordpress-website-vm:/home$ ls
bitnami  officialdataguild
officialdataguild@wordpress-website-vm:/home$ cd bitnami/
officialdataguild@wordpress-website-vm:/home/bitnami$ ls
bitnami_credentials  htdocs  stack

officialdataguild@wordpress-website-vm:/home/bitnami$ test ! -f "/opt/bitnami/common/bin/openssl" && echo "Approach A: Using system packages." || echo "Approach B: Self-contained installation."
Approach A: Using system packages.
officialdataguild@wordpress-website-vm:/home/bitnami$ sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status
apache already running
mariadb already running
php-fpm already running
```

But I still can't find the theme live preview logs ...

Comment: I haven't watched the YouTube video but I think you're deploying the site to a Compute Engine VM. `gcloud app` commands are specific to App Engine which is a different Google compute service and unrelated to your issue. If you can identify the VM's instance name, you can `gcloud compute ssh {instance-name} --project={your-project}` (replacing with actuals) to SSH into the VM.

Comment: The error message means that WordPress has a fatal error. You will find details of that error in the WordPress/Apache log files. Most likely you did not set up **wp-config.php** correctly or the database (MySQL) is not set up correctly for WordPress. Delete your question and repost on the WordPress site after you have details from the log files: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for your comment @DazWilkin ! I just tried but it seems the command can't overcome this authorization scope problem

Comment: Thanks for your comment @JohnHanley unfortunately I am not able to get the logs yet. Do you know how to widen my access scope so I can get access to the log files from GCP VM?

Comment: The logs are on the VM. You already have permission. Google search for tutorials on how to debug WordPress. This is a very basic problem. You just need to understand how WordPress works - at least the installation and setup portion.

Comment: And, just to confirm, you must have run `gcloud auth login` (using your Gmail account) to authenticate before you can run other `gcloud` commands including `gcloud compute ssh`. The `gcloud compute ssh` command that you tried appears to be correct otherwise. You need only run `gcloud auth login` once but do it first.

Comment: Bitnami provides technical support for installation and setup issues through its [support center](https://bitnami.com/support/google).